# html/jquery dropdown menu with a href and div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Does someone have any idea how to make instead of this

```html
    <select id="drop">
       <option value='table1'>table1</option>
       <option value='table2'>table2</option>
    </select>
```

a dropmenu like this

```html
    <div class='dropdown'>
    <button class='dropbtn'>Current choice<i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i></button>
    <div class='dropdown-content'>
    <a>table1</a>
    <a>table2</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I thought it was not possible because you need to reload the page for this and that is not possible in php or atleast not without ajax. Here is a jsfiddle with the first one [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qze3nqrb/)

The dropdown contains tables that have to be shown and not shown when selected, so you select table1 , table1 is shown and when you select table2, table2 is shown but table1 is hidden again.

Why I want to change it is because you cant really use css on a dropdown so it looks pretty ugly.

Someone any idea or atleast let me know if it is even possible

Thankyou

Comment: It's not clear, what is your problem. According to your jsfiddle you have a working example with `<select>`. To make dropmenu with `<a>` just change your handler from `$("#drop').change()` to `$(".dropdown-content a').click()`

Comment: I wish it was that easy

Comment: But that is easy. Check my answer. Hope this is what you was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I hope this is what you need. I copied all your html from jsFiddle, and replaced `select` with `div` dropdown.

Here is `div` dropdown html:

```
<div class='dropdown'>
  <button class='dropbtn'>
    Current choice
    <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>
  </button>
  <div class='dropdown-content'>
    <a href="#table1">table1</a>
    <a href="#table2">table2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //hide both tables and dropdown on page-load
  $("table, .dropdown-content").hide();

  //to make dropdown work
  $(".dropbtn").click(function() {
    //changes show/hide state
    $(".dropdown-content").toggle();
  });

  //fires when <a> in dropdown is clicked
  $(".dropdown-content a").click(function(event) {
    //prevents page refresh
    event.preventDefault();
    //hides both tables
    $("table").hide();
    //shows only desired
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    //modifies text in button
    $(".dropbtn").find("i").text(" " + $(this).text());
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it only really interferce with my plugin datatables so I need to change some things but this will help me already . :)

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to reinvent the wheel. So, I suggest that you make use of a UI framework such as Bootstrap (dropdowns), or better yet, jQuery-UI (selectmenu) since you're already making use of jQuery.